# is_email() function Not Validating within Foreach Loop

Tags: email

Developing a plugin that register's WP users with a CSV upload. In the validation process of email, I'm using the [`is_email()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_email) function, but it's returning the opposite of what's expected. All the emails return `FALSE` except the last value returns `TRUE` and will register the user. Also I'm validating the email domain which is also failing. I've stared at this code for hours and new eyes to look at it to tell me what I'm missing. Thanks.

Below is the CSV data, PHP script, and validation output I'm debugging with.

### CSV Data

```
first,last,username,email  
John,Doe,johndoe,John.Doe@email.com
JANE,DOE,JANEDOE,JDOE@EMAIL.COM 
Bob,Smith,bobsmith,Bob.Smith@email.com
Bill,Nelson,BILLNELSON,BILL.W.NELSON@EMAIL.COM
```

### PHP Code

```
  $csv_row = file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name']);

  // loop around
  if (is_array($csv_row)) {
    foreach (array_slice($csv_row,1) as $row) {

      // split into values
      $csv_data = explode(",", $row);

     // Take forth value $csv_data[3] which is the email
     $email = $csv_data[3];

     //Verify domains
     $email_domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);
     $domains = array('Email.com', 'EMAIL.COM');


          // Validate email format
          if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
            echo '<p><code>' . $email . ' is not a valid email.</code></p>';
          } else {
            echo '<p><code>' . $email . ' is a valid email.</code></p>';
          }

         // Validate email domain 
          if ( !in_array($email_domain, $domains)) {
            echo '<p><code>' . $email_domain . ' is not a valid email domain.</code></p>';
          } else {
            echo '<p><code>' . $email_domain . ' is a valid email domain.</code></p>';
          }
      }
    }
```

### Output

```
John.Doe@Email.com is not a valid email.
Email.com is not a valid email domain.

Jane.Doe@Email.com is not a valid email.
Email.com is not a valid email domain.

Bob.Smith@Email.com is not a valid email.
Email.com is not a valid email domain.

BILL.W.NELSON@EMAIL.COM is a valid email.
EMAIL.COM is a valid email domain.
```

Comment: does your CSV file have whitespace? leading or trailing whitespace will fail validation.

Comment: Not that I can see. It's exactly how I've displayed it as it shows in Submile Text 2. Also I use  `trim()` in the sanitize process.

Comment: [have a look at the filter for `is_email` which will let you determine how it's failing](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2115)

Comment: I've actually successfully tested these emails with `is_email()` by passing them one at a time but once I pass them through `foreach` all at once, I get this behavior.

Comment: changing `$email = $csv_data[3];` to `$email = trim($csv_data[3]);` results in all emails validating, so it does appear to be characters in your csv file at fault.